# Use method in sql interpolator

Tags: sql, scala, unit-testing, junit, slick

Using scala 2.11 and Slick 2.11

In a scala class, I have 2 methods:

- getSQL which returns String SQL
- getSqlStreamingAction which returns a composed SqlStreamingAction using sql interpolator

The code

```
def getSQL(id: Int): String = {
    var fields_string = "";
    for ((k,v) <- field_map) fields_string += k + ", ";
    fields_string = fields_string.dropRight(2) // remove last ", "
    "SELECT "+ fields_string +" FROM my_table WHERE id = " + id
  }

def getSqlStreamingAction (id: Int): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[OtherObject], OtherObject, Effect] = {
    val r = GetResult(r => OtherObject(r.<<, r.<<))

    // this works
    var fields_string = "";
    for ((k,v) <- field_map) fields_string += k + ", ";
    sql"""SELECT #$fields_string FROM my_table WHERE id = #$id""".as(r)

    // But I want to use the method getSQL to retrieve the SQL String
    // I imagine something like this, but of course it doesn't work :)
    //sql"getSQL($id)".as(r)
```

I want to have separated methods for unit tests purposes, so I want to use getSQL method for sql interpolator

So, how can I use a method for Slick sql interpolator?

Note: I'm pretty new in Scala

Answer (score 0):

-1 for me.

Solution:

```
def getSqlStreamingAction (id: Int): SqlStreamingAction[Vector[OtherObject], OtherObject, Effect] = {
    val r = GetResult(r => OtherObject(r.<<, r.<<))

    var sql_string: String = getSQL(id)
    sql"""#$sql_string""".as(r)
```